# Wordpress pages creation work distribution & then combining - Localhost XAMPP

Tags: pages, import, export, version-control

Is there any best practice for distributing Pages creation work amongst 4 people and then exporting & combine all their work.

I was thinking for following steps:

- creating XAMPP setup on each system
- install duplicator backup
- let all 4 create their set of pages
- export pages using Wordpress Export tool
- Import all pages to the main localhost system's site

Will there be any issue while importing?(since all are on localhost)

Will there be any conflict in page-id?(since all start from the same duplicator backup, their pages will have identical ids)

Will there be conflict arising to page data connected with plugin tables, example, Advanced Custom Fields, Yoast, etc?

PS: **this is the actual problem**, "distributing page creation work & then combining". I want to avoid giving access to all on a staging site, as then I would have to reverse the workflow. Currently, it goes from Localhost to Staging site via duplicator backup restore.

Answer (score 2):

> Will there be any issue while importing?(since all are on localhost)

Yes and no. The content will be fine, as will the posts. Any images uploaded on the other hand will be problematic. This is because it will need to download those images from the original host, which won't be possible when using a local environment.

> Will there be any conflict in page-id?(since all start from the same duplicator backup, their pages will have identical ids)

No, the page IDs would get recreated with new values on import

> Will there be conflict arising to page data connected with plugin tables, example, Advanced Custom Fields, Yoast, etc?

Data in custom tables doesn't get saved in a WXR export. Neither do options, only post related content. You would need to ask the support avenues of the relevant plugins, or try this out for yourself

---

My recommendation, would be to just create 4 users on a staging site, and avoid using localhost and import/export altogether. This should eliminate the issues.

However, it sounds like you're trying to do this to solve a problem or requirement that you have not shared. Perhaps if you asked how to solve/fulfil that problem rather than asking about a proposed solution, you would get a more useful answer.

Comment: this is the actual problem, "distributing page creation work & then combining the work done". I want to avoid giving access to all on a staging site, as then I would have to reverse the workflow. Currently, it goes from Localhost to Staging site via duplicator backup restore.

Comment: You could just give them the author role so they can only edit their own pages?